# Autohotkey: Google Chrome doesn't react for Send, ^+y

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, autohotkey

Here is an [extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yawas-web-highlighter/kjlghdmljfgngjdpeaiogebkiilpiimk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) with hotkeys you can not change. So I write a script to remap default hotkey `Ctrl-Shift-Y` to `Alt-1`.

```
(Default header here is omitted)

#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
!1::
   Send, ^+y
Return
```

And it works but very unstable. Usually there are periods of working and nonworking goes consequently, swaps with no visible reason. Reboots of Chrome or the script doesn't help.

When it doesn't work I still can see log entries. And I've check `ahk_class` which is known to be mutable for Google Chrome - problem is not there.

```
008: Send,^+y
009: Return (3.56)
```

Comment: "!1" is "Alt-1" and you want to use "Ctrl-1".

Comment: @user3419297 oh, just a mistake in my post. I've fixed it.

Comment: Try replacing "!1" with "~!1" or with " ~LAlt & 1". https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde. See also https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm

Comment: @user3419297 no success :(

Comment: What extension are you using? The content of the website cited changes regularly.

Comment: @user3419297 I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try...

1. Replace `SendPlay` with `SendInput` (or vice versa, depending on what default is)
2. Try holding down the modifiers yourself when the script executes and see if that changes anything
3. Split the send statement into 2 parts and put a delay on the modifiers before the trigger key is sent
4. Try sending the keystrokes to a different upper level window or control hwnd
5. Make sure you do not have a privilege mismatch with the process running that you're trying to send to (highly unlikely since it's a browser--just a thought)

Item 3 Example:

```
Send {LShift Down}{LControl Down}
Sleep 1000        ; lower this to something reasonable if a long delay works
Send y{LControl Up}{LShift Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). with this you can change the hotkeys in chrome extensions page (at the end of the page)

Comment: I used it, but stopped in favor of Yawas because of lack of synchronization.

Comment: In order to write a good answer, please add more than just a link. Read [answer] before answering next time.

Comment: @user99572isfine: okay

Answer (score 0):

My current dirty workaround is to emulate context menu click instead of hotkeys pressing.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
~LAlt & 1::
   Send, {AppsKey}
   Sleep, 100
   Send, y
   Sleep, 100
   Send, y
Return
```